# Reloading GXT grid on pagination events

Tags: gwt, pagination, gxt

I am having Ext-GWT Grid which is using PagingModelMemoryProxy, BasePagingLoader and PagingToolbar. All is working well until one requirement.

I want my grid to reload the data from server when i click on Next, Previous, Last, First or Refresh. What i did is overridden the pagingtoolbar methods and capture the pagination events. Now when user clicks on next it first do pagination event and then server to reload data. When client receives data from server it tell grid to reload it.

Here everything is working fine, but as you can see the Load event is getting fired twice. First for pagination event and other when new data arrived from server.

Now my question is what should i do to resolve this requirement? I know RpcProxy can work for me but i cant change the server methods and also i dont have normal asynccallback for server calls. Can any one suggest what should i do which will work with PagingModelMemoryProxy, BasePagingLoader only?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
loader.setFiresEvents(false);
```

In addition, to stop incoming events you can call:

```js
event.setCancelled(true);
```

which will aggregate both `cancelBubble()` and `stopPropagation()`.